# Swapping images in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to swap four images on a single screen . The images can be swapped only in left/right/upwards/downwards directions only and not diagonally . For example , the 1st image can be swapped with the images on its right and below it , the 2nd image can be swapped only with the one on the left and below it , and so on . Can anyone please help me about how to do it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add drag and drop functionality, assuming that is what you mean, you'll want to look into [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uipangesturerecognizer%20class%20reference&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2Fuikit%2Freference%2FUIPanGestureRecognizer_Class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=6Fw3UN3nJJGO9ASzr4CQBg&usg=AFQjCNHxg0rarekmj02GP3au0hipPRU-ig&sig2=iQEBPzoed64LvUV8nWgHkA)

Answer (score 0):

Add a swipe gesture recognizer. When the user swipes determine which direction and handle the image swap.

[EDIT] - Imagine a square divided into four equal sections. The top left section has an index of zero, the top right an index of one, the bottom left an index of 2 and finally the bottom right an index of 3. The code below checks the current index and from that it determines if an image swap can be made, if not it does nothing.

This code is from the top of my head so there may be syntax errors but the logic is sound (I hope :D ).

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
// turn on user interaction on the image view as its off by default.
[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

self.currentImageIndex = 0;
self.images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-left"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-right"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom-left"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"top-right"],nil];

}


-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {

if (self.currentImageIndex == 0 || self.currentImageIndex == 2) self.currentImageIndex++; // change to image to the right
else return; // do nothing

}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

if (self.currentImageIndex == 1 || self.currentImageIndex == 3) self.currentImageIndex--; // change to the image to the left
else return; // do nothing

}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {

if (self.currentImageIndex == 2 || self.currentImageIndex == 3) self.currentImageIndex -= 2; // change to the above image 
else return; // do nothing

}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {

if (self.currentImageIndex == 0 || self.currentImageIndex == 1) self.currentImageIndex += 2; // change to the above image 
else return; // do nothing

}
[UIView animationWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.imageView setAlpha:0];
} completion^(BOOL finished){
    if (finished) {
         [UIView animationWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
             [self.imageView setImage[self.images objectAtIndex:self.currentImageIndex]];
             [self.imageView setAlpha:1];
         }];
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: its not according to my expectation,please send me another answer.

Comment: I edited the post to include a working solution instead of sudo code.